# JHipster - Failed to run task: 'npm run webpack:build' failed

Tags: maven, npm, webpack, jhipster

Using JHipster latest version, I have created monolithic application.   When I try to build the application I am getting the following error message.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goalcom.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.10.0:npm (webpack build dev) on project m-bees: Failed torun task: 'npm run webpack:build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited withan error: 134 (Exit value: 134)
```

Comment: You have an error on front-end build post the complete build log.